# Is there a way of detecting the end of an HLS stream with javascript

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, quicktime, http-live-streaming

I am being served a video over http by a third party and I am never notified when the stream has ended. I would like to know if there is a way to detect that the stream has ended thorugh javascript. At the moment, when the stream is over, the player just freezes and eventually errors which is something I do not want. I need to know the precise moment that I get the last frame so that I can show a dialog or some sort of message to notify the user that the stream has ended. I am using the HTML5 video tag and a custom player on andorid (I am aware that android has some issues with hls as it is). On quicktime, it freezes and stays like that for a while then it throws up a dialog that reads "could not load movie".

So far I have tried the ended property but that never changes to true when the stream ends. I have tried checking both network and media errors but they are never constant so they are not reliable at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The end of the HLS stream is signaled in the stream itself using the `EXT-X-ENDLIST` tag. Check if it's the case.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that with javascript, is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, I meant manually checking if the tag appears in the playlist at the end. The player should already detect the end of the stream.

Comment: #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=48000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
http://110821-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ruk91hls_0@118577/index_150_a-b.m3u8?sd=2&rebase=on

That is pretty much the last line of the playlist and it there is no EXT-X-ENDLIST tag.

Comment: That's the master playlist, you need to check the variant streams. Use VLC using the extra verbose mode `vlc http://../playlist.m3u8 -vvv`. Watch till the end of the stream, it will periodically display the contents of the playlist. Check the last entry before the stream ends.

Comment: I have done that this morning and there doesn't seem to be an end tag at the end of the video

Comment: So it seems your source stream is invalid. Try to play the following stream in your player `http://playertest.longtailvideo.com/adaptive/bbbfull/bbbfull.m3u8`

Comment: When the video ends, the video element seems to disappear and the whole element goes black